# Position node left alinged below of opamp

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

How can I draw a node below an opamp (from `circuitikz`) so that the edges on the left side align? Here a small example:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[op amp] (opamp) {};
        \node[draw, below=2 of opamp.west, anchor=west] (node) {node};

        \draw (opamp.+) -- ++(-1,0) |- (node.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: illustration of problem]

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't look like `circuitikz` defines any anchors along the left vertical line of `op amp` (see manual section 6.1.4). You could of course place it relatively to one of the existing anchors and shift it a bit, but as it's just trial and error it's not a very good solution.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[op amp] (opamp) {};
        \node[draw, below=1.5cm of opamp.+, xshift=3.5mm,anchor=west] (node) {node};

        \draw (opamp.+) -- ++(-1,0) |- (node.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found that `circuits` manual is deficient. In it I miss (for many circuits shapes) data, where are their anchors, how far are from main shape (for examples, input anchors from front of amp shape). This information are hidden in code, however for an average user is not so simple digging in it. Nice solution (+1), I allow myself to add picture in your answer generated with your MWE.

Comment: I have added  new anchor "leftedge" at the opamp/gmamp symbols for easier positiong in the future: https://github.com/circuitikz/circuitikz/commit/54938061af34a31f1e5cadc50d7111378cfd3d6a